# Expansion of $\big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\big)^n$ in little oh notation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

The sequence
$$ \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^n \to 1$$
as $n$ tends to infinity.

I'd like to expand it in little oh notation, i.e. write
$$ \Big(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^n = 1 + o(...)$$
again, as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Taylor around what ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: start from the binomial expansion
$$1+n\frac1{n^2}+\binom n2\frac{1}{n^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{2n}},$$
bound each term individually, and add them up.

Comment: I think I understand. The $i$-th term is of the order of $\frac{1}{n^i}$. So the answer I'm looking for is $(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^n = 1 + O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Especially Lime's approach via the binomial theorem is the quickest. You may also argue as follows. The logarithm of your expression is

$$n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

But for $x\in(-1,1]$ we have

$$\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$$

as $x\to 0$, so, with $x=n^{-2}$, for $n\geq1$ we have

$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=n^{-2}+o(n^{-2})$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Hence the logarithm of your expression is $n^{-1}+o(n^{-1})$. This alone is enough to see that your limit is $1$, since if the logarithm vanishes in the limit, then the expression tends to $1$.

But if you require an estimate for the original expression rather than the logarithm, you may take the exponential and use the Taylor series for $e^x$, which gives the little-oh estimate $1+n^{-1}+o(n^{-1})$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You may also note that $(1+n^{-2})^{n}=\big(\color{blue}{(1+n^{-2})^{n^2}}\big)^{1/n}$. The blue expression tends to $e$, while $1/n$ tends to zero, so the whole expression tends to $1$.